# Can I use a 3rd party GPL2+/LGPL2+ library in an MPL 2 licenced iOS app?

Tags: ios, license, dynamic-library

I'm thinking of using libmpv to provide video playback in my MPL 2 Flutter app. I know that Apple is weird about GPL stuff (and using GPL stuff in a greater work is awkward), so I was just wondering if I was actually allowed to.

Here's the source code if it matters: https://github.com/UnicornsOnLSD/finamp

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is nothing to do with Apple software or hardware - In this case look at the Open Source Stack Exchange where this will have been answered many times - or else look at how to choose a license on github - also not LGPL and GPL are rather different to each other in your use case

Comment: The only version of this question on topic here might be “ does Apple say anything about intellectual property in the review guidelines” and that answer would basically end up with  ***talk to your lawyer***. [“Make sure your app only includes content that you created or that you have a license to use.”](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#legal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not really come into the equation here. There are no rules stating that you must specific open source licenses or anything like that.

In order to publish app on the App Store you need to have properly licensed code. It doesn't matter which license it is as such, you just need to have the rights to use the code in the manner you're choosing to do so.

If you want to know about combining (L)GPL code with MPL code in general, you can find a very thorough and practical set of instructions here:

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/combining-mpl-and-gpl/

Comment: Note that if you include GPL (not LGPL) code then your app has to be licenses as GPL. You have to get agreement of all the authors of that code to put your app in Apple's App Store

Comment: This is not because of rules by Apple but because of the GPL.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Apple - it's just how the GPL license works. Note that in this particular case, the code he wants to use is ISC-licensed backed by a LGPLv2+ core.